# How can I deal with this nloptr error in R?

Tags: r, nlopt

```
init_nloptr.c:35:10: fatal error: 'nlopt.h' file not found
#include "nlopt.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [init_nloptr.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'nloptr'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/nloptr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'nloptr' had non-zero exit status
```

I got this error message when I installed nloptr package which need to install mi package.

Answer (score 1):

From the path showing up in the error message, it looks like you're running on macOS.

If so, you must install the `nlopt` system library before installing `nloptr`.

Hopefully you have Homebrew installed (if not, please reply/comment and I will attach some further info), hence open the Terminal and run

```
brew install nlopt
```

At the end of the `brew install` command, go back to `R` and install `nloptr`.